# Purpose of a lock when using SWP in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

The following table contains ARM assembly code for a lock.

```
try: MOV R3,#1
SWP R2,R3,[R1,#0]
CMP R2,#1
BEQ try
LDR R4,[R2,#0]
ADD R3,R4,#1
STR R3,[R2,#0]
SWP R2,R3,[R1,#0]
```

My question is what is the purpose of branching back to try when R2 is equal to 1? From what I understand if this branch executes then something was wrong with the SWP operation but I don't know the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hard to infer the exact details without some higher-level context, but this looks like it might be some kind of ticket lock/semaphore/atomic increment. It would seem that `r1` holds the address of a pointer-to-atomic-data kind of variable which itself acts as the mutex:

```
try: MOV R3,#1
SWP R2,R3,[R1,#0]
```

At this point, we've atomically stored the value 1 to the location pointed to by `r1`, and retrieved the value which was there into `r2`. There are now two possibilities: either it already contained 1, in which case the `swp` hasn't actually changed anything, or it contained a different value.

```
CMP R2,#1
BEQ try
```

If the previous mutex value *was* 1, then that implies the lock is currently taken: imagine a second copy of this code running in parallel but slightly later - the first guy will have swapped in 1, so the second guy will see it and try again, spinning on the `r1` location until it contains something other than 1 again. If it wasn't 1, then the mutex *was* unclaimed, but by virtue of the `swp`, the value there *is* 1 now, so we hold the mutex and can proceed.

```
LDR R4,[R2,#0]
ADD R3,R4,#1
STR R3,[R2,#0]
```

This implies the 'unclaimed' mutex value, now in `r2`, is also actually a pointer to the data of interest: we increment that, knowing that the read-modify-write here is effectively atomic by virtue of the mutex.

```
SWP R2,R3,[R1,#0]
```

...and here I have no idea<sup>*</sup>. Swapping the incremented data back into the mutex itself doesn't seem to make much sense - if it's not 1 then it would appear to release the mutex, but it seems highly unlikely that "some value + 1" is going to be a valid 4-byte-aligned pointer were we (or some other agent in the system) to now run through this code again. I can only imagine this snippet is an incomplete part of something more complicated.

<sub>* For simply releasing the mutex as I've imagined it so far, I'd expect `r2` to be written back, not `r3`.</sub>